# How to change the LinkButton forecolor in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am doing project for a mobile company.
Where the home page will display all the mobile's with LinkButton
which will take us to respective mobile's detail when we clicks that.
the thing is i want to change the forecolor of the selected linkbutton using C# codings.

Eg :

asp.net :

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="MobileLinkButton" runat="Server" OnClick="MobileDetailslinkButton_Onclick" ForeColor="White" />
```

C# :

> protected void MobileDetailslinkButton_Onclick(object sender, EventArgs e)
>       {
>           Response.Redirect("~/MobileDetails.aspx");
>           MobileLinkButton.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
>
> ```
> }
> ```

But the ForeColor is not changing,but the rest is working good.

Note : these linkbutton's are all in MasterPage which is been used in my whole project's all the pages.

Comment: The linkbutton in the aspx code binds to a different event than the one you show in the code behind. Furthermore, you are doing a redirect and then change the color, which will not work since you are starting a new page cycle with the redirect.

Comment: yeah sorry for that .... i have changed that now... Thanks a ton :)

Comment: actually i even gave that responseredirect as a last line...but still its not working fine....

Comment: @Rajesh, since you're redirecting to another page, anything you did in the current page is lost. Whether you change the link's color before or after redirecting is irrelevant. To solve your problem, you have to change the link's color from the *other page*'s code.

Comment: No matter where you put it. When you click and the redirect is called, the current page cycle will be stopped before it renders to the client and start a new page cycle to the redirected page and render that instead.

Comment: The question is, what are you trying to accomplish with a white link after it's clicked? Does it act like a menu on the master page and you want to show the active one?

Comment: @all : thanks u very much guys....i used PostBackUrl in asp.net instead of response.redirect in C#....now its working good... thanks a ton friends :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you probably want to do this using CSS and not in the code behind. Try having a look at the CSS `:visited` selector. Something like below should do the job.

```
a:visited
{ 
    color:yellow;
}
```

Comment: thanks u very much friend....i used PostBackUrl in asp.net instead of response.redirect in C#....now its working good... thanks a ton friend :)

Answer (score 1):

By using CSS you can change fore color

```
  <style>
     .ClassName
      {
       color:Green;
       }
    </style>
   <asp:LinkButton ID="id1" runat="server" CssClass="ClassName"  Text="Link"></asp:LinkButton>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a CSS for that,

     .myclass
      {
       color:Green;
       }